# When is it appropriate to send Seasons Greetings?

Tags: american-english, letter-writing, religion, valediction

During what time of the year is it appropriate to close semi-formal written conversation with "Season's Greetings"?

Obviously sometime around December 25th, but how much in advance and how much past this date?

Or isn't it ever?

Comment: As formulated, this appears to be a question of customs and etiquette, but it could be reformulated as a question that is arguably a matter of usage of the word *season*: e.g. 'What exactly is the season that is referred to in the phrases such as *season's greetings* and *holiday season*?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about social customs rather than the English Language. When it was originally posted it should have been bumped to ELL. Now it should be quietly strangled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, in the US it's appropriate from roughly now (Dec 7) through Jan 2 or so.  Usually by about the 7th of January folks are tired enough of the Christmas season that they don't really care to hear it.

Answer (score 5):

When I worked in the centre of the British Civil Service as long ago as the 1970s, there was a form of correspondence between one ministry and another that was formally known as 'semi-official'. The practice then was to end a semi-official letter with some reference to seasonal greetings

1. if it was the last letter you expected to send to that person before the Christmas holiday, and
2. if you were writing to someone to whom you wrote fairly frequently.

No such pleasantry could be included in an official letter, because that would have to end with the words:'I am, Sir, your obedient servant...'. (I swear I did not make that up: I have actually signed such letters.)

It is now very many years since I have seen any reference to seasons greetings in business correspondence.